# Not sure why this function does not preform the proper math

Tags: python, function, math, printing, return

```
def main():
    num = 5
    triple(num)
    print(num)

def triple(num):
    num = 3 * num

main()
```

This came directly from my Python textbook. When ran, it just returns 5. So, maybe it's not supposed to "triple" the number. But, I would've expected it to return 15 based on just looking at the code. So, how would I change the output of the code from 5 to 15?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value. Below will print 15.

```
def main():
    num = 5
    triple(num)
    print(triple(num))

def triple(num):
    num = 3 * num
    return num

main()
```